# Display an array in a readable/hierarchical format without mess up the path

Tags: php, arrays, pretty-print

I have an array

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Xperia Z Ultra"
    "img" => "xperia-z-ultra.jpg"
    "img_path" => "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/site/public/images/photos/devices/"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▶]
  2 => array:3 [▶]
  3 => array:3 [▶]
  4 => array:3 [▶]
  5 => array:3 [▶]
  6 => array:3 [▶]
  7 => array:3 [▶]
  8 => array:3 [▶]
  9 => array:3 [▶]

]
```

I want to make it pretty so I did this

```
$pretty_devices = json_encode($devices, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

## VIEW

```
<div><pre>{{$pretty_devices}}</pre></div>
```

I got it display in pretty format as I wanted, but it kind mess up my

**img_path**.

How do I stop that ?

Comment: `$pretty_devices = json_encode($devices, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` if the only problem you have is the escaped backslashes... there's a number of formatting-related JSON constants. `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` and `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` are bitmasks, (values 128 and 64), so combining them with the bitwise `|` operator will combine the two

Comment: Wow, this is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to see it nicely try print_r() instead.

```
echo "<div><pre>".print_r($pretty_devices, true)."</pre></div>"
```